# groupby multiple columns, subset rows based on multiple conditions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Give dataframe `df` as follows:

```
          date indicator_name region_code date_freq     data_type     value
0    2023/3/31            GDP          BJ         Q  actual_value  8.200000
1    2023/6/30            GDP          BJ         Q  actual_value  8.400000
2    2023/3/31            GDP          BJ         Q    arima_mape  0.331838
3    2023/6/30            GDP          BJ         Q    arima_mape  0.269978
4    2023/9/30            GDP          BJ         Q    arima_mape  0.208118
5   2023/12/31            GDP          BJ         Q    arima_mape  0.146257
6    2023/3/31            GDP          BJ         Q       es_mape  0.084397
7    2023/6/30            GDP          BJ         Q       es_mape  0.022536
8    2023/9/30            GDP          BJ         Q       es_mape -0.039324
9   2023/12/31            GDP          BJ         Q       es_mape -0.101184
10   2023/1/31            CPI          SH         M  actual_value  1.900000
11   2023/2/28            CPI          SH         M  actual_value  1.700000
12   2023/3/31            CPI          SH         M  actual_value  1.400000
13   2023/4/30            CPI          SH         M  actual_value  1.100000
14   2023/5/31            CPI          SH         M  actual_value  0.800000
15   2023/6/30            CPI          SH         M  actual_value  0.600000
16   2023/7/31            CPI          SH         M  actual_value  0.400000
17   2023/1/31            CPI          SH         M    arima_mape  1.964911
18   2023/2/28            CPI          SH         M    arima_mape  1.934797
19   2023/3/31            CPI          SH         M    arima_mape  1.569138
20   2023/4/30            CPI          SH         M    arima_mape  1.284494
21   2023/5/31            CPI          SH         M    arima_mape  0.940008
22   2023/6/30            CPI          SH         M    arima_mape  0.698891
23   2023/7/31            CPI          SH         M    arima_mape  0.557101
24   2023/8/31            CPI          SH         M    arima_mape  0.331838
25   2023/9/30            CPI          SH         M    arima_mape  0.269978
26  2023/10/31            CPI          SH         M    arima_mape  0.232883
27  2023/11/30            CPI          SH         M    arima_mape  0.212634
28  2023/12/31            CPI          SH         M    arima_mape  0.219534
29   2023/1/31            CPI          SH         M       es_mape  1.425995
30   2023/2/28            CPI          SH         M       es_mape  1.897687
31   2023/3/31            CPI          SH         M       es_mape  1.697817
32   2023/4/30            CPI          SH         M       es_mape  1.410244
33   2023/5/31            CPI          SH         M       es_mape  1.085284
34   2023/6/30            CPI          SH         M       es_mape  0.810315
35   2023/7/31            CPI          SH         M       es_mape  0.585306
36   2023/8/31            CPI          SH         M       es_mape  0.440354
37   2023/9/30            CPI          SH         M       es_mape  0.452097
38  2023/10/31            CPI          SH         M       es_mape  0.492415
39  2023/11/30            CPI          SH         M       es_mape  0.504193
40  2023/12/31            CPI          SH         M       es_mape  0.487353
```

Assuming `df` contains two sets of data: `BJ`'s quarterly `GDP`'s `actual_value`, `arima_mape`, and `es_mape`, `SH`'s monthly `CPI's` `actual_value`, `arima_mape`, and `es_mape`. For each group of `indicator_name`, `region_code`, `date_freq`, I need to use the actual value's latest date as the current time node to subset, if the group is quarterly data (`date_freq=='Q'`), the historical values of the latest two quarters will be kept, `arima_mape` and `es_mape` of the latest two quarters and the next quarter. If it is monthly data (`date_freq=='M'`), it is required subset the *historical data* of the latest 4 months (2023/4/30~2023/7/31), the last 4 months (2023/4/30~2023/7/31) and the next month (2023/8/31) of `arima_mape` and `es_mape`. How can I modify the function below to obatin the expected output as follows? Thanks.

```
         date indicator_name region_code date_freq     data_type     value
0   2023/3/31            GDP          BJ         Q  actual_value  8.200000
1   2023/6/30            GDP          BJ         Q  actual_value  8.400000
2   2023/3/31            GDP          BJ         Q    arima_mape  0.331838
3   2023/6/30            GDP          BJ         Q    arima_mape  0.269978
4   2023/9/30            GDP          BJ         Q    arima_mape  0.208118
5   2023/3/31            GDP          BJ         Q       es_mape  0.084397
6   2023/6/30            GDP          BJ         Q       es_mape  0.022536
7   2023/9/30            GDP          BJ         Q       es_mape -0.039324
8   2023/4/30            CPI          SH         M  actual_value  1.100000
9   2023/5/31            CPI          SH         M  actual_value  0.800000
10  2023/6/30            CPI          SH         M  actual_value  0.600000
11  2023/7/31            CPI          SH         M  actual_value  0.400000
12  2023/4/30            CPI          SH         M    arima_mape  1.284494
13  2023/5/31            CPI          SH         M    arima_mape  0.940008
14  2023/6/30            CPI          SH         M    arima_mape  0.698891
15  2023/7/31            CPI          SH         M    arima_mape  0.557101
16  2023/8/31            CPI          SH         M    arima_mape  0.331838
17  2023/4/30            CPI          SH         M       es_mape  1.410244
18  2023/5/31            CPI          SH         M       es_mape  1.085284
19  2023/6/30            CPI          SH         M       es_mape  0.810315
20  2023/7/31            CPI          SH         M       es_mape  0.585306
21  2023/8/31            CPI          SH         M       es_mape  0.440354
```

So far, my trial code generates error:

```
import pandas as pd

def get_rows(group):
    group['date'] = pd.to_datetime(group['date'])
    group = group.set_index('date').sort_index()

    if group['date_freq'].iloc[0] == 'Q':
        actual_value_max_date = group[group['data_type'] == 'actual_value'].index.max()
        actual_value_dates = pd.date_range(end=actual_value_max_date, periods=2, freq='Q')
        mape_dates = pd.date_range(start=actual_value_max_date - pd.offsets.QuarterEnd(1), periods=3, freq='Q')
    else:  # 'M'
        actual_value_max_date = group[group['data_type'] == 'actual_value'].index.max()
        actual_value_dates = pd.date_range(end=actual_value_max_date, periods=4, freq='M')
        mape_dates = pd.date_range(start=actual_value_max_date - pd.offsets.MonthEnd(3), periods=5, freq='M')

    actual_value = group.loc[group.index.intersection(actual_value_dates) & (group['data_type'] == 'actual_value')]
    arima_mape = group.loc[group.index.intersection(mape_dates) & (group['data_type'] == 'arima_mape')]
    es_mape = group.loc[group.index.intersection(mape_dates) & (group['data_type'] == 'es_mape')]

    return pd.concat([actual_value, arima_mape, es_mape])

df.groupby(['indicator_name', 'region_code', 'date_freq']).apply(get_rows).reset_index()
```

Out:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3553, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-17-6689e28504c3>", line 20, in <cell line: 20>
    df.groupby(['indicator_name', 'region_code', 'date_freq']).apply(get_rows).reset_index()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 331, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 6361, in reset_index
    new_obj.insert(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4817, in insert
    raise ValueError(f"cannot insert {column}, already exists")
ValueError: cannot insert date_freq, already exists
```

Comment: Given the complexity of the requirements, I would split the data frame into four smaller ones, each handling one (data_freq, data_type) combination. The group by logic for the smaller data frame would be much easier to handle. The smaller data frames can be merged together once they are all processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error arises because, after the `groupby` and `apply` operations, the grouped columns (`indicator_name`, `region_code`, `date_freq`) become indices of the resulting dataframe. When you call `reset_index()`, pandas tries to add these columns back into the data frame as columns, but they already exist, causing the error. Here's the corrected co

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample data
data = {
    'date': ['2023/3/31', '2023/6/30', '2023/3/31', '2023/6/30', '2023/9/30', '2023/12/31', '2023/3/31', '2023/6/30', '2023/9/30', '2023/12/31', '2023/1/31', '2023/2/28', '2023/3/31', '2023/4/30', '2023/5/31', '2023/6/30', '2023/7/31', '2023/1/31', '2023/2/28', '2023/3/31', '2023/4/30', '2023/5/31', '2023/6/30', '2023/7/31', '2023/8/31', '2023/9/30', '2023/10/31', '2023/11/30', '2023/12/31', '2023/1/31', '2023/2/28', '2023/3/31', '2023/4/30', '2023/5/31', '2023/6/30', '2023/7/31', '2023/8/31', '2023/9/30', '2023/10/31', '2023/11/30', '2023/12/31'],
    'indicator_name': ['GDP', 'GDP', 'GDP', 'GDP', 'GDP', 'GDP', 'GDP', 'GDP', 'GDP', 'GDP', 'CPI', 'CPI', 'CPI', 'CPI', 'CPI', 'CPI', 'CPI', 'CPI', 'CPI', 'CPI', 'CPI', 'CPI', 'CPI', 'CPI', 'CPI', 'CPI', 'CPI', 'CPI', 'CPI', 'CPI', 'CPI', 'CPI', 'CPI', 'CPI', 'CPI', 'CPI', 'CPI', 'CPI', 'CPI', 'CPI', 'CPI'],
    'region_code': ['BJ', 'BJ', 'BJ', 'BJ', 'BJ', 'BJ', 'BJ', 'BJ', 'BJ', 'BJ', 'SH', 'SH', 'SH', 'SH', 'SH', 'SH', 'SH', 'SH', 'SH', 'SH', 'SH', 'SH', 'SH', 'SH', 'SH', 'SH', 'SH', 'SH', 'SH', 'SH', 'SH', 'SH', 'SH', 'SH', 'SH', 'SH', 'SH', 'SH', 'SH', 'SH', 'SH'],
    'date_freq': ['Q', 'Q', 'Q', 'Q', 'Q', 'Q', 'Q', 'Q', 'Q', 'Q', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'M'],
    'data_type': ['actual_value', 'actual_value', 'arima_mape', 'arima_mape', 'arima_mape', 'arima_mape', 'es_mape', 'es_mape', 'es_mape', 'es_mape', 'actual_value', 'actual_value', 'actual_value', 'actual_value', 'actual_value', 'actual_value', 'actual_value', 'arima_mape', 'arima_mape', 'arima_mape', 'arima_mape', 'arima_mape', 'arima_mape', 'arima_mape', 'arima_mape', 'arima_mape', 'arima_mape', 'arima_mape', 'arima_mape', 'es_mape', 'es_mape', 'es_mape', 'es_mape', 'es_mape', 'es_mape', 'es_mape', 'es_mape', 'es_mape', 'es_mape', 'es_mape', 'es_mape'],
    'value': [8.2, 8.4, 0.331838, 0.269978, 0.208118, 0.146257, 0.084397, 0.022536, -0.039324, -0.101184, 1.9, 1.7, 1.4, 1.1, 0.8, 0.6, 0.4, 1.964911, 1.934797, 1.569138, 1.284494, 0.940008, 0.698891, 0.557101, 0.331838, 0.269978, 0.232883, 0.212634, 0.219534, 1.425995, 1.897687, 1.697817, 1.410244, 1.085284, 0.810315, 0.585306, 0.440354, 0.452097, 0.492415, 0.504193, 0.487353]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Convert date column to datetime format directly
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

def get_rows(group):
    # Set the date column as the index and sort by it
    group = group.set_index('date').sort_index()
    
    # Identify the latest date for the actual values within the group
    max_date_actual = group.loc[group['data_type'] == 'actual_value'].index.max()
    
    # Depending on the frequency ('Q' for quarterly, 'M' for monthly), determine the desired date ranges
    if group['date_freq'].iloc[0] == 'Q':
        actual_value_dates = pd.date_range(end=max_date_actual, periods=2, freq='Q')
        mape_dates = pd.date_range(start=max_date_actual - pd.offsets.QuarterEnd(1), periods=3, freq='Q')
    else:  # 'M'
        actual_value_dates = pd.date_range(end=max_date_actual, periods=4, freq='M')
        mape_dates = pd.date_range(start=max_date_actual - pd.offsets.MonthEnd(3), periods=5, freq='M')

    # Filter the rows of the group based on the specified criteria:
    # 1. Rows with actual values within the desired date range
    rows_actual_value = group.loc[group.index.isin(actual_value_dates) & (group['data_type'] == 'actual_value')]
    # 2. Rows with forecast values (arima_mape and es_mape) within the desired date range
    rows_forecast = group.loc[group.index.isin(mape_dates) & group['data_type'].isin(['arima_mape', 'es_mape'])]

    # Concatenate and return the filtered rows
    return pd.concat([rows_actual_value, rows_forecast])

# Apply the function to groups defined by 'indicator_name', 'region_code', and 'date_freq'
# This ensures that the function is applied separately for each combination of these columns
results = df.groupby(['indicator_name', 'region_code', 'date_freq'], sort=True).apply(get_rows).reset_index(level=[0,1,2], drop=True).reset_index()

# Finally, sort the resultant dataframe by 'region_code' and 'data_type' columns
result_sorted = results.sort_values(by=['region_code', 'data_type']).reset_index(drop=True)

# Display the sorted results
print(result_sorted)
```

which results in

```
         date indicator_name region_code date_freq     data_type     value
0  2023-03-31            GDP          BJ         Q  actual_value  8.200000
1  2023-06-30            GDP          BJ         Q  actual_value  8.400000
2  2023-03-31            GDP          BJ         Q    arima_mape  0.331838
3  2023-06-30            GDP          BJ         Q    arima_mape  0.269978
4  2023-09-30            GDP          BJ         Q    arima_mape  0.208118
5  2023-03-31            GDP          BJ         Q       es_mape  0.084397
6  2023-06-30            GDP          BJ         Q       es_mape  0.022536
7  2023-09-30            GDP          BJ         Q       es_mape -0.039324
8  2023-04-30            CPI          SH         M  actual_value  1.100000
9  2023-05-31            CPI          SH         M  actual_value  0.800000
10 2023-06-30            CPI          SH         M  actual_value  0.600000
11 2023-07-31            CPI          SH         M  actual_value  0.400000
12 2023-04-30            CPI          SH         M    arima_mape  1.284494
13 2023-05-31            CPI          SH         M    arima_mape  0.940008
14 2023-06-30            CPI          SH         M    arima_mape  0.698891
15 2023-07-31            CPI          SH         M    arima_mape  0.557101
16 2023-08-31            CPI          SH         M    arima_mape  0.331838
17 2023-04-30            CPI          SH         M       es_mape  1.410244
18 2023-05-31            CPI          SH         M       es_mape  1.085284
19 2023-06-30            CPI          SH         M       es_mape  0.810315
20 2023-07-31            CPI          SH         M       es_mape  0.585306
21 2023-08-31            CPI          SH         M       es_mape  0.440354
```

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me solve this complex problem.